# LSTM, seq to classification, why training on balanced data set yields such a good result?

Tags: neural-network, lstm, overfitting, oversampling

I am using LSTM to classify the origin of people's names.

The input data is not balanced over target classes, so I used oversampling to balance it.
[image]

Now, I defined a simple LSTM model as follows:

```
LSTM_with_Embedding(
  (embedding): Embedding(32, 10, padding_idx=31)
  (lstm): LSTM(10, 32, batch_first=True)
  (linear): Linear(in_features=32, out_features=18, bias=True)
)
```

First, I trained this model using the unbalanced data, and got the following results:
[image]

Clearly, I am in the overfitting zone.

Before I fix this overfitting, I used the same model, but now trained with the balanced training dataset, I kept the test-set unbalanced only to represent the actual world. And the performance is:
[image]

How can the performance be so good? Why not overfit now?